# Can you submit for journal publication an institutional working paper?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, online-publication, preprint

Journals are nowadays fairly open to preprints before submission (e.g. Nature policies here https://www.nature.com/nature-portfolio/editorial-policies/preprints-and-conference-proceedings). However, are they okay with institutional working papers?

For example, can I publish my work as an IMF or World Bank working paper and then submit the manuscript to a journal? I would some substantial change text and figures to fit scope but the results would be based on the same work (data + code).

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by a “working paper”? In general if something is already published in some way, and you try to publish it in an academic journal it will be considered plagiarism. As you highlighted, preprints are an exception to this.

Comment: @leonos At least in economics and adjacent fields, working papers are essentially what other fields call preprints, but it is conventional that a working paper is distributed via an institutional working paper series. These series are maintained by university departments or other research organisations, with varying degrees of "reviews". As far as I understand, all economics journals should treat these as unpublished.

Comment: I see! That looks like a question for the specific journal that you’re aiming to publish in…

Comment: Yes, I meant an institutional working paper as in IMF working paper or World Bank working paper. Thanks @jnanin this makes me more confident I can still submit for journal publication.